How to speed up a spatial filter query for polygon-features that intersect with a sf-POINTs object in R
I have large geopackage (around 2.5 million features, about 3Gb) with spatial polygons representing all agricultural fields in my country. Most of them are shaped rectangular-ish. I don't need this entire dataset and would only need the polygons that intersect with a my other dataset of sf-points. I have about 4.000 points, but spread across the country. Calculating a bounding box for the points therefore wouldn't really make much of difference. I want to do this in R.
The example below is fast enough, but the polygon-geopackage is very large. With just about 4.000 observation points it takes over 30 min to execute.
In it's simplest form I'm doing the following:
    library(tidyverse)
    library(sf)
    
    map_file <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")
    map <- st_read(map_file)

    ## Get some random points to filter later
    points <- st_sample(map, size = 2) |> st_as_sf()
    points_wkt <- points |> st_union() |> st_geometry() |> st_as_text()

   ## Filter the states based on the points
   st_read(map_file, wkt_filter = points_wkt)

This works but is extremely slow. How can I speed it up for the large geopackage?

Have you tried reading the points and polygons into sf objects, and using st_intersects? Is there a typo in the last line (should be point_wkt to work with the previous line)? How fast is acceptable? Note that the geopackage file size is almost irrelevant, how many polygons are there, and how detailed are they? Rectangular polygons are much easier to operate on than polygons with 10000 vertices...

I don't know any R, but if I understand the code correctly, you union all points to one multipoint and use that to filter. This is bound to give very bad performance on large datasets as it will make it impossible to use the spatial index properly. Even though it will also be very inefficient, just reading and filtering the points one per one might be significantly faster still. An efficient solution would be to write the points to a/the file and do a spatial join on the two tables.

points are in sf-object.  The polygon geopackage contains about 2.5 million features and mostly rectancular-ish shaped but defintely not all of them. Would R be able to handle this when loaded as an sf? That's the reason why I want to perform filtering before loading. Looping of the points and using st_intersects is the fastest option so far.

Try loading it. It will depend on how much RAM your computer has. If it can't its possible to load parts using SQL queries, work on those, and then merge. Spatial indexing will make it run at lightning speed. Compare finding a word in an alphabetic dictionary with finding a word in an unsorted list of words - it can be that effective with point-in-which-polygon searches.

After 30 min it was still not loaded into R, so I don't think that's going to work well. I was trying on a simple laptop, but will also try on a more decent PC.

Can you tell how many features (polygons) it has? I think you may have to use the divide-and-conquer method and read as much as you can using a query argument in st_read to read in chunks of some size using the FID column probably...

The polygon-geopackage contains about 2.5 million features. I updated my original post to include that information.

I'm afraid I don't know any R, but I'll try to explain an approach that should be fast and is most likely as easy to implement in R as it is in python.
Based on the documentation, st_read supports a parameter query where you can pass a SQL statement.
Especially because you are filtering using Points, it is relatively easy to encode/embed the points you want to filter on as a "fake", "on-the-fly" table in a SQL query. This wat it is not needed to save the points in a/the file and still filter on them in bulk. Just like any other table, you can use it to apply a filter on your polygon table efficiently using the "spatial index table" that is typically available for each GIS layer in a Geopackage file.
The query you need to execute looks as follows, with an example for 5 points, but it will work for 5.000 as well. The table/layer name in my case is "prc2023", you'll have to change that on the two relevant places in the query:
    SELECT polys.*
      FROM "prc2023" polys
      JOIN "rtree_prc2023_geom" polys_tree ON polys.fid = polys_tree.id
      JOIN (SELECT ST_Point(143235.05884403182, 188742.4711590528) AS geom
UNION ALL SELECT ST_Point(143378.84542967367, 188592.96964570132) AS geom
UNION ALL SELECT ST_Point(141859.5100542316, 188311.13036137863) AS geom
UNION ALL SELECT ST_Point(141915.01060649645, 188252.16092147244) AS geom
UNION ALL SELECT ST_Point(143179.8708224297, 188299.47967988) AS geom
        ) points
    WHERE ST_MinX(points.geom) <= polys_tree.maxx
      AND ST_MaxX(points.geom) >= polys_tree.minx
      AND ST_MinY(points.geom) <= polys_tree.maxy
      AND ST_MaxY(points.geom) >= polys_tree.miny
      AND ST_intersects(polys.geom, points.geom) = 1

As asked in the comment, some more info on how the SQL query actually works:

SELECT polys.* : please retrieve all columns available in the "polys" table. "polys" is the alias given to the table/layer with the polygon data you want to filter on in the Geopackage file in the next line.
FROM "prc2023" polys : we want to use the table "prc2023" available in the Geopackage file, and we give it an alternative name "polys" for use in this SQL query. The double quotes around the table name are a good practice because they will avoid problems if the table name contains "special characters", like e.g. '-'.
JOIN "rtree_prc2023_geom" polys_tree ON polys.fid = polys_tree.id : in geopackage files, typically a spatial index is automatically created for each GIS layer. By convention, this (virtual) table is named "rtree_" + table_name + geometry_column_name. The geometry_column_name is typically "geom". The spatial index table will make it very fast to do a "rough" filtering on the location of the geometries in a layer/table. The "rough" filtering is in practice a filtering on the MBR (minimum bounding rectangle) of the geometries in the spatial index. "Enterprise GIS databases" like Oracle Spatial and PostGIS will ~"hide" the fact that you need to use the spatial index for fast filtering and do this for you. In Geopackage files you need to do this yourself via this JOIN.
JOIN (SELECT ST_Point( : You can JOIN with another table/layer in the Geopackage file, but in SQL you can also create a "fake" table on the fly by using (SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... UNION ALL ...) table_name to specify the data you want in this "fake" table. In this case you want a "fake" table with one column with a lot of Point geometries. The way you create a Point geometry is with the function ST_Point(x, y). I don't know any R, but most likely you can loop over all points you are work with, extract the x and y coordinate from them and concatenate them together to get the string you need here to create this "fake" points table.
WHERE ST_MinX(points.geom) <= polys_tree.maxx AND ... : Now you have specified the tables to be used, you can now specify what filtering you want to be applied using the WHERE SQL clause. Here you specify that you want to filter using the spatial index ("polys_tree"), using the points in the "points" table.
AND ST_intersects(polys.geom, points.geom) = 1: The spatial index only does "rough"/"first pass" filtering very fast, so you need to specify as well what kind of "detailed"/"second pass" you want applied on all polygons that are "in the neighbourhood" of a point. So you want the point to intersect with the polygon to retain the polygon.

I suppose it is possible to generate a SQL statement like that using string concatenations?
Sample script (in python):
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd

poly_path = Path(r"C:\temp\prc2023\prc2023.gpkg")

points_gdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\temp\prc2023\prc2023.gpkg", rows=5, engine="pyogrio")
points_gdf.geometry = points_gdf.geometry.centroid
layername = poly_path.stem

point_selects = [
    f"SELECT ST_Point({x}, {y}) AS geom"
    for x, y in points_gdf.geometry.get_coordinates().values.tolist()
]
points_unionall = "\nUNION ALL ".join(point_selects)

sql = f"""
    SELECT *
      FROM "{layername}" polys
      JOIN "rtree_{layername}_geom" polys_tree ON polys.fid = polys_tree.id
      JOIN ({points_unionall}
        ) points
    WHERE ST_MinX(points.geom) <= polys_tree.maxx
      AND ST_MaxX(points.geom) >= polys_tree.minx
      AND ST_MinY(points.geom) <= polys_tree.maxy
      AND ST_MaxY(points.geom) >= polys_tree.miny
      AND ST_intersects(polys.geom, points.geom) = 1
"""
print(f"{sql}")
polygons_gdf = gpd.read_file(poly_path, sql=sql)

print(polygons_gdf)


I think I understand the lines with the ST_POINTS. This is now hardcoded to serve as an example, but I imagine this can also be an sf-feature I have loaded seperately in R? Or does it need to be in the same geopackage as the polygons-layer?
I'm not sure I understand the second and third line. Where does the polys_tree come from and why do I need to join it with the polygon-feature?

Not sure how much SQL you know, but I gave a try to add some explanation on how the SQL statement works...
